# Java, JSTL, MySql, Apache Tomcat 6 - Data not retrieved - Session Issue

Tags: java, mysql, session, jstl, tomcat6

I am shiva, developing an dashboard application in Java, JSTL, MySql, Apache Tomcat 6.
I have the below files
1. Dashboard.java (model)
2. DashboardDAO.java (dao)
3. DashboardController.java (Controller)
//Source

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
                forward = LIST_DASHBOARD;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("dboard", dao.getAlldashboard(req));
        setMasterInfo(req);
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(req, res);
    }
```

//Source 
4. Dashboard.jsp (view)
//Source

```
  <c:forEach items="${dboard}" var="dbrd">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${dbrd.dname}" /></td>
                        <td style="display: none;"><c:out value="${dbrd.did}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${dbrd.pname}" /></td>
                        <td style="display: none;"><c:out value="${dbrd.pid}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${dbrd.wname}" /></td>
                        <td style="display: none;"><c:out value="${dbrd.wid}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${dbrd.lname}" /></td>
                        <td style="display: none;"><c:out value="${dbrd.lid}" /></td>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd MMM,yyyy" value="${dbrd.trns_date}" /></td>
                        <td align="right"><c:out value="${dbrd.units}" /></td>
                        <td align="right"><c:out value="${dbrd.dunits}" /></td>
                        <td align="right"><c:out value="${dbrd.variance}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${dbrd.notes}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

//source
5. web.xml
//source

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>dboardtest</display-name>
       <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>dashboard.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

//source

It works in the first time.  But, after sometime the data is not retrieved and display empty screen.  Once, i stop and start the server again, the data is getting retrieved again.  But, later when we refresh the empty page is getting displayed again. 
Help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Shiva.

Comment: This might be the problem with Session Management. if i give HttpSession session = req.getSession(false); the data will get removed  during navigating to other pages.  I am very poor in session management. anyone can help me?

Comment: I know it's been a long time now. Were you able to solve this issue or still looking for the solution ? If you have solved then share your solution ...